# Changing the file names and copying into different directory

Tags: linux, string

I have some files say about 1000 numbers.. Wanted to rename those files in such a way that, wanted to cut out only few chars from file name and copy it to some other directory.

Ex:  Original file name.

```
vfcon062562~19.xml
vfcon058794~29.xml
vfcon072009~3.xml
vfcon071992~10.xml
vfcon071986~2.xml
vfcon071339~4.xml
vfcon069979~43.xml
```

Required O/P is cutting the ~and following chars.
O/P Ex:

```
vfcon058794.xml
vfcon062562.xml
vfcon069979.xml
vfcon071339.xml
vfcon071986.xml
vfcon071992.xml
vfcon072009.xml
```

But want to place n different directory.

Comment: What tools / language are you using for this? Like this, you can get a million answers in different languages. What have you *tried* to solve the issue and where did you get stuck?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using bash or similar you can use the following simple loop:

```
for input in vfcon*xml
do
  mv $input targetDir/$(echo $input | awk -F~ '{print $1".xml"}')
done
```

Or in a single line:

```
for input in vfcon*xml; do mv $input targetDir/$(echo $input | awk -F~ '{print $1".xml"}'); done
```

This uses awk to separate everything before ~ using it as a field separator and printing the first column and appending ".xml" to create the output file name. All this is prepended with the targetDir which can be a full path.

If you are using csh / tcsh then the syntax of the loop will be slightly different but the commands will be the same.

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution.. Am sorry didn't mentioned about requirement in detail.. File names could be any thing but, from that i wanted to remove ~and following numbers till dot. Extension may be .jpg or xml like.. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

I like to make sure that my data set is correct prior to changing anything so I would put that into a variable first and then check over it.

`files=$(ls vfcon*xml)
echo $files | less`

Then, like @Stefan said, use a loop:

`for i in $files
do
    mv "$i" "$( echo "$file" | sed 's/~[0-9].//g')"
done`

If you need help with bash you can use http://www.shellcheck.net/